# How should I create a REST API using Rails 3.0?

Tags: xml, api, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't seem to find much information on the web about the different approaches to building a REST API in Rails; so I kinda have two questions:

1. **Can someone point me to some articles that show the pros/cons of the different
   approaches?**
2. **Would you please share your thoughts on the pros/cons of the following approaches?**

### Proposed Approaches

1. **Use the standard controllers to return XML when a users adds `.xml` to the end
    of the URL**

   ***Pros:***

   - This is built-in to Rails and very easy to use
   - Follows the same resource-based approach that Rails has, so it will be easy for
     existing users to understand/remember

   ***Cons:***

   - API isn't cleanly separated from the main site, harder to maintain
   - People may assume that adding `.xml` will work in places it doesn't
2. **Use namespaced routing to create separate API controllers that only handle API
    functions, but still have access to the same models that the website uses**

   ***Pros:***

   - API is mostly separated
   - Still uses resource-full controllers

   ***Cons:***

   - URLs have the form of site.com/api/resource.xml which may make people assume all
     resources are available
   - API is still part of the website code/project; thus, harder to maintain
3. **Use route forwarding and constraints to forward all API calls to a Rack
    application**

   ***Pros:***

   - API is fully separated
   - Not required to use Resource-full style if we don't want to
   - URLs clearly show it's an API and you should check the docs to see what's available
     (at least, my mind works this way; I assume other dev's minds do too)

   ***Cons:***

   - Harder to use models from website code
   - Easier to maintain as a separate project, but that means harder to integrate with
     existing site
   - Must keep codebases in sync since models may change for site features/bug fixes

Comment: @abatishchev - I'm not going to revert it back, but may I ask why you removed all of my formatting? I think it made it easier to separate the questions, and it was suggested by others on meta SO that I make my questions bold so that they were more visible and easier to read.

Comment: Actually, I would revert it. It was miles easier to read.

Comment: @Topher: Could you please give a link on Meta considering this topic? I concur that bold is bad idea for idea highlighting, if your prefer to do so, it's better to use italic, imo, isn't it?

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop: Easier to read? Disputable. And dazzled

Comment: @abatishchev - Here is my question on Meta SO regarding how to make my questions more readable. The answer with the most votes regards highlighting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62420/136658

Comment: @Topher: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62420/how-can-i-improve-my-questions-so-that-they-are-answered/62994#62994

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would propose that the API being in the same project as your website isn't a bad thing as long as the code is DRY*. Like you pointed out, having separate codebases is a challenge because you have to keep them in sync with every feature/bugfix you do. It's easier to maintain if they are in the same place. As long as you keep your code DRY, this method is the clear winner.

I would offer XML and JSON from the controllers with a subdomain handled by Rails's routing engine. When someone has picked up on the pattern of api.site.com/resource.xml and tries to access a resource that isn't there, it's really not a big deal. As long as your API is documented clearly and you fail/error gracefully when they try to access a resource not in your API, it should be just fine. I would try to return a message saying that resource isn't available and a url to your api documentation. This shouldn't be a runtime problem for any API consumers, as this should be part of discovering your API.

Just my $0.02.

*DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself. DRY code means you don't copy-paste or rewrite the same thing for your site and your api; you extract and call from multiple places.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Would you mind elaborating just a bit on offering XML/JSON from the controllers and router-based subdomain? Are you saying I should offer a subdomain for only a specific format (JSON/XML) or action in the controller?

Comment: @Topher Fangio: use the Rails3 routing to set up a subdomain api.site.com. From there, do your #2 option. Instead of site.com/api/resource.xml you offer api.site.com/resource.xml. It's almost just cosmetic compared to your second option. My main point was your CONs against #2 aren't really all that bad, or preferable to the alternative.

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop - I understand you now. Thanks very much for clearing that up.

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop - I wanted to apologize for not awarding you the full bounty. I went out of town this weekend and was unexpectedly without an Internet connection and wasn't able to check in on this. Again, I apologize. Thank you very much for your answer though!

Comment: @Topher Fangio No problem. I'm not a hardcore rep-farmer, so I'm plenty content with 50.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution for you is to merge your first two points.

I suggest using JSON instead of XML: the only point in favor of XML is XPath which is useless in returned data. JSON leads to better response time (and more readable data for better debugging ! :p). Plus, most languages can read JSON. For instance, PHP can natively parse JSON to array/object with `json_decode`, so it's a nice point. ;)

For controllers, you can namespace it but it's not an obligation, maybe it's better in certain cases to avoid fat actions with tons of conditions. With the Rails 3 router, the separation of API calls in a subdomain (api.webapp.com) is trivial).

For the model, sure you should use the same as used in the whole application.

The new rails router syntax is sugar, you will enjoy. Good luck & have fun! :)

Comment: All languages have bindings to work on XML. XPath is a nice way to query a returned response. Your assertion that JSON leads to better response time is useless: not based on facts. JSON has the same duplication that XML suffers from. Both are highly compressible using gzip, which is what should be done.